# Can anyone identify this military uniform?

Tags: military, identification, uniform

Can anyone identify this uniform? I'm not sure it is military or scouts? I'm guessing this is WWII era or earlier in the United States.[image]

Comment: No verbose verbal description. Useless for the blind and search engines. Close

Answer (score 4):

The [ten-pointed star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Legion#/media/File:American_Legion_Seal_SVG.svg) on the lapel, and cap form makes this image readily identifiable to anyone familiar with the [American Legion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Legion) organization.

[image]

The three digit number indicates the 'Post' the individual belonged to, with this one indicating a connection to [Johnston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnston,_Iowa), Polk County, Iowa (part of Des Moines metro area). Not enough detail at this resolution to pick out what the smaller pins on the cap may represent.

Though [eligibility requirement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Legion#Eligibility) for membership indicates this individual served in the military, it does not indicate which branch of service.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate this informative answer!